# Reading and writing data to ElastiCache Redis cluster using RestAPI service

Tags: asp.net, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an ElastiCache cluster and an EC2 instance already setup. Now, I want to save some data (e.g. list) to the Redis elasticache cluster BUT only by using Rest API service. Does ElastiCache have an API endpoint which allows to add or remove my data inside a cache cluster? If so, then how can i do that?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm also interested. I have a elasticache redis cluster. Which library did you pick to interact with the cache?

Comment: @LarsAnundskås I finally used Redis StackExchange client libary for c#. Hope it helps you.